# Flutter Button It should be pressed once in a day

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, fluent-nhibernate, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Is there any where I can make a button to be pressed only once in a day.
You cannot press that button again in that day.
you need to wait till next day inorder to press it again

```
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("Once in a day");
                        title = "Change Date";
                      },
                      child: Text(title),
                    ),
```

Comment: Find someplace to store data, sql/sharedPref. on Mypp check `DataTime.now().day`  compare with stored Dated. You don't need a button to be pressed, i think you want to run a function. else, use Global key to presss the button

Comment: Thanks brother 
its completely helpful brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your onPress function,

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final currentTime = DateTime.now();
    DateTime resetTime = DateTime.parse(prefs.getString("time"));
    
    if(resetTime != null && !compareDate(currentTime, resetTime))
                                    prefs.setBool("one_tap", true);
                                  
      if(prefs.getBool("one_tap") == null || prefs.getBool("one_tap")){
          print("Once in a day");
          title = "Change Date";
          prefs.setBool("one_tap", false);
          prefs.setString("time", currentTime.toString());
         }
},
child: Text(title),),

compareDate(DateTime current, DateTime reset) {
    if (reset != null) {
      return current.year == reset.year &&
          current.month == reset.month &&
          current.day == reset.day;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a function toDate that converts a dateTime to a date. Then you wrap the content of onPressed with an if condition in which you check if the last date saved (you can save it using userPreferences or sqflite) is not equal to the currentDate. If this is the case the content of onPressed is executed. When that is finished you need to save the current Date using userPreferences or sqflite so that you can check next time the user presses the button if it has already been pressed that day.
Here is a small code snippet.

```
///takes a dateTime and returns the date belonging to it
DateTime toDate(DateTime time) {
  return DateTime(time.year, time.month, time.day);
}

String title = "";
st() {
  return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (/*check if the date the button was pressed the last 
      time is not equal to the toDate(DateTime.now())*/) {
        print("Once in a day");
        title = "Change Date";
        //save the toDate(DateTime.now()) using 
        //shared Preferences or sqflite
      }
    },
    child: Text(title),
  );
}
```